# mvc 3 force the query to display in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem with search box. So here is the code to generate the form.

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search"))
    {

            <input name="query" type="text" />
            <input type="submit" />

    }
```

and the route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Search",
            "Search",
            new { controller = "Search", action = "Index"}
            );
```

So basically right now when user types in something in search box and clicks the button, it takes him to url `/Search` and displays the search value. But I would like to have `/Search?query=searchedvaluehere`. Also when I manually type in /Search?query=something it does search for `something`. So all I need is to have the query in the URL to appear automatically.

The Controller action looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string query)
{
//some code here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the form action to `get`, instead of `post`, which is the default. There's an overload of `Html.BeginForm()` which lets you set that.

```
Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Get)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `method` to `get`

You should use the `Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Get)`

**reference**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform.aspx